# Low Pass Filter in AM Demodulation

Tags: matlab, filters, fourier-transform, filter-design, digital-communications

I am trying to recover my baseband signal that was AM modulated. I am using the filter command in MATLAB to perform the low pass filtering ...the code is given below:

```
Fsig=10;                    Fc=100;              Fsamp=10.*Fc;
t = 0:1/Fsamp:2*pi;

Tx = cos(2.*pi.*Fsig.*t);               % Transmitted Signal
Carrier = cos(600.*t);                  % Carrier Signal
Modulated = Tx.*Carrier;                % Modulated Signal
Demodulated = Modulated.*Carrier;       % Demodulated Signal

Rx= filter([1 1],[1 -0.8],Demodulated);

figure(6);
plot(t,Tx,'r',t,Modulated,'b',t,Demodulated,'g',t,Rx,'k','LineWidth',1.5); grid on;
legend('Trans.','Modulated','Demodulated','Baseband')
```

How can I select the coefficients of the filter to perfectly recover my baseband signal?
Is there any other technique/command that can be used in matlab to recover the baseband signal other than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has `amdemod` (see [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/amdemod.html)) which can be used to recover suppressed carrier AM modulated signal. From the documentation, the demodulator uses a low-pass filter generated using `[num,den] = butter(5,Fc*2/Fs)`. This can be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

In your simulation, the sampling frequency is 1000 Hz, which means the Nyquist frequency is 500 Hz. The carrier frequency is very close to 95.5 Hz (`600/(2*pi)`). The message has frequency 10 Hz. This means the signal `Demodulated` has harmonics at frequencies 10, 181, and 201 Hz. So, the cut-off frequency of your low-pass filter can be set at any frequency above 10 and below 181. Let's say you want it at 100 Hz. Matlab has many commands to design filters. A simple one is `fir1`:

```
b = fir1(10,100/500);
```

The `100/500` is your cutoff frequency divided by the Nyquist frequency. The first argument, `10`, is the filter order.

To recover the message, you can convolve `Demodulated` with the filter's impulse response `b`:

```
Rx = conv(Demodulated, b);
```

By the way, I would change the name of the signal `Demodulated`, since it's not really demodulated yet. A better name might be `rx_mixed` or something along those lines.